# git not tracking folder and files?

Tags: git

I am working on a project following [Elixir's tutorial](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/task-and-gen-tcp.html). I created a git repo named `kv_umbrella`. At some point, I dragged and dropped my `kv` folder inside `kv_umbrella/apps`. But somehow git is not tracking anything inside `kv` folder.

Github repo [here](https://github.com/IggHub/kv_umbrella).

If you go to the github repo and go inside apps, it is empty. However, in my local laptop, I have contents.

[image: kv folder]

When I `git status`, it shows that I have nothing to add:

```
kv_umbrella iggy$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

There is another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721624/github-changes-not-staged-for-commit) with issue similar to mine, but none of the top solutions worked.

I have tried `git add .` (after making changes in one of the files inside `kv`)

I also tried adding the file manually, but this is what shows up:

```
kv_umbrella iggy$ git add apps/kv/README.md
fatal: Pathspec 'apps/kv/README.md' is in submodule 'apps/kv'
```

What should I do to tell git to push `kv` folder content?

Comment: if you don't want to use as git submodule, delete all .git* related files inside `kv` and try to `git add`, hope will work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It didn't track anything inside kv, because kv was recorded by its main parent repo as a gitlink.

That is, a special entry in the parent index, recording only the SHA1 of the tree represented by the kv sub-repo.

Instead of dragging it, you could reference it as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.
Another approach would be [subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309).

Or, if you don't care about the history of kv, simply remove its .git subfolder (then kv content will be added).

In the meantime, to remove the empty folder on GitHub:

```
git rm --cached apps/kv
# no trailing slash!

git commit -m "remove gitlink"
git push
```