# Why does Vue code can't be pushed to github?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, github

I've tried to push my project including Vue code using the below commands.

```
git remote add origin <repository_url>
git add *
git commit -m "your commit message"
git push -u origin master
```

But all my vue code located in the `vue-passport` folder is ignored. So, I am not able to push vue code to Github. FYI: I am using `vue-cli` to build my vue project along with Laravel.

When I use the below commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
or
git status
```

It produces an error:

```
On branch master
Changes were not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in the working directory)
(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
    modified:   vue-passport (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

This is my `.gitignore` inside `vue-passport` folder

```
.DS_Store
node_modules
/dist


# local env files
.env.local
.env.*.local

# Log files
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
pnpm-debug.log*

# Editor directories and files
.idea
.vscode
*.suo
*.ntvs*
*.njsproj
*.sln
*.sw?
```

And this is my `.gitignore` file in Laravel.

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.env.backup
.phpunit.result.cache
docker-compose.override.yml
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
/.idea
/.vscode
```

Comment: Could you paste here a "git status" output and the contents of your ".gitignore"? It will be helpful

Comment: Try **git add .** instead git add *

Comment: this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/5126905/4575350

Answer (score 0):

Take a pull then try to commit

```
git pull

git add .

git commit -m 'Your message'

git push
```

Comment: Please take a look to my question. There is error message right there. `modified content, untracked content`

Comment: what is the output of git status?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721624/github-changes-not-staged-for-commit/33797015